# Can’t deselect previously selected cell when a new one is selected in a tableview where each cell contains tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview, where each cell is a custom tableview cell. That custom tableview cell contains a tableview and a label.
Lets say, the outer tableview is called MainTableView. Each cell of MainTableView consists another tableview. The problem is , when I select 
inner tableview cell one by one the previously selected cell is not get deselected.In first image I have selected cell contains text “Two”. Then  In the second image I have selected cell contains text “Five” but perviously selected cell  “Two” still in selection mode. I want to deselect the previous cell when select a new one.

[image: First Image] [image: Second Image]

I have tried

```
tableView.deselectRow(at: IndexPath, animated: Bool)
```

this method inside didSelectRowAt in custom tableviewcell class but it didn’t serve the purpose because the previous indexPath is from seperate tableview.  So, how can I deselect the previous one?

Comment: First get first tableview indexpath then get InsideTableview and deselect that row at selected indexpath

Answer (score 1):

to get the correct inner tableView,

**Firstly** , you should record the outside tableView's cell indexPath, which cell the inner tableView is in.

So your should record two indexPathes

```
var selectionRowInfo: (lastOutsideIP: IndexPath?, lastInnerIP: IndexPath?)
```

**Secondly**, you get the correct tableView, via the outsideTableView.

**if the inner table is visible,** you shall handle it immediately. through `outTableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows`

**the else condition**, you need not handle it. The tableView reuse mechanism will refresh its state.

```
    // pseudo code.


    if let lastOut = lastOutsideIP, let visibleRows = outTableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows, visibleRows.contains(lastOut){
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: lastOut) as! YourCell
        // get the correct inner tableView via the cell
    }
```

---

Because the inner tableViews are not related to each other. Select the cell of table one, will not affect the selection of cell of table two.

So your should build the connection manually.

Use a property to store the state `var lastIndexPath: IndexPath?`,

then every time select a indexPath,

```
  // pseudo code.
  if let last = lastIndexPath{
        tableView.deselectRow(at: last, animated: true) 
  }
```

Please notice that, you should find the correct inner tableView, which has the `lastIndexPath`

Comment: what is the best way to get correct inner tableView?

Comment: Updates. `Via the cell` , the cell should have some method to handle its inner tableView .

Comment: I have solved the problem and add an answer here but not sure this is the best way

Comment: It consumes memory, cell reuse mechanism does not work well .

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is along the right lines but has a flaw - it cannot distinguish between tableViews, which is the most important part.  Also if the tableViews have different numbers of rows, it risks trying to access a row that doesn't exist and causing a crash.

To track the selected row in two tableViews (`tv1` & `tv2`) you'll need to hold the selected row in each:

```
var tv1, tv2: UITableView!
var lastRowForTV1, lastRowForTV2: IndexPath?
```

and then respond to selections by identifying the tableView being used and adjusting the other (this assumes the two tableViews use the same datasource/delegate)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      if tableView === tv1 {
         lastRowForTV1 = indexPath
         if let last = lastRowForTV2 {
            tv2.deselectRow(at: last, animated: true)
            lastRowForTV2 = nil
         }
      } else if tableView === tv2 {
         lastRowForTV2 = indexPath
         if let last = lastRowForTV1 {
            tv1.deselectRow(at: last, animated: true)
            lastRowForTV1 = nil
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: number of inner tableview is not fixed like you answered , it can be 10 or 20 or any number around 20

Comment: @Asif that was my point - you need a solution that can cope with variable number of rows.  Which is the solution above, and why the earlier one will risk crashes.

Comment: Yes , maybe the table view in the cell is not exist, because the cell reuse mechanism,  Can solve it by `outTableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows`

Comment: Are you saying that your outer table could have around 20 cells, each containing their own tableView?  If so (a) you could adapt the above answer to use an array to hold the data with either a tuple or simple struct for holding a reference to each tableView and it's last index  and (b) I'd say you should rethink your UI as that sounds like highly processor intensive, confusing to code, and even more confusing to troubleshoot.  Why not just use the outer array with sections rather than subarrays?

Comment: and using visible rows wouldn't work, as you'd need to track all the offscreen ones so you can update them when they scroll back in.

Comment: you are right that outer table could have around 20 cells, each containing their own tableView . I have solved the problem and add an answer here but not sure this is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by using the idea of first answer given by  dengApro . The idea was to find the correct inner table which contains the previously selected cell.
I have two files one is ViewController.swift that contains the outer tableview MainTableView. Another one is CustomTableViewCell.swift with CustomTableViewCell.xib that contains the custom cell with tableview.

```
fileprivate var lastSelectedInnerTableView : Int = -1
fileprivate var lastSelectedRow: Int = -1
fileprivate var tableViewList :[UITableView] = []
```

I have added these 3 variables in CustomTableViewCell.swift file outside the class CustomTableViewCell. lastSelectedSection , lastSelectedRow these 2 variable are used to keep 
track of the last selected inner tableview (lastSelectedInnerTableView) and the last selected cell of that inner tableView (lastSelectedRow). tableViewList variable is used to keep the 
Inner tableView. Inside awakeFromNib()  I have append the created inner tableviews.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    tableViewList.append(self.tableView) // append the created inner tableviews
}
```

Then inside didSelectRowAt I have deselect the previous one:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if lastSelectedInnerTableView != -1 && lastSelectedRow != -1{
        self.oldIndexPath.section = 0
        self.oldIndexPath.row = lastSelectedRow
        tableViewList[lastSelectedInnerTableView].deselectRow(at: self.oldIndexPath, animated: true)
    }

    lastSelectedInnerTableView = self.innerTableId
    lastSelectedRow = indexPath.row
}
```

In ViewController.swift  I have set innerTableId inside cellForRowAt

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let customCell: CustomTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell") as! CustomTableViewCell
    customCell.innerTableId = indexPath.row
    customCell.customCellActionDelegate = self

    return customCell
}
```